# How the output is calculated as 98,67?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FNC(x,y)((x) > (y)) ? (x * y): (y - x);

int main() {
    int p = 7, q = 6, r = 4;

    r += FNC(++p, q++);
 
    printf("%d%d,%d", p, q, r);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `98,67`

Can you help me with how this output is calculated?

Comment: Looks like `p` is `9`, `q` is `8`, and `r` is `67`. Maybe this helps you figuring out.

Comment: What specific help are you looking for? Expand the macro, and evaluate the (admittedly confusing) expression by hand. Where do you get stuck when you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `r += FNC(++p, q++);` expands to:

```
r += ((++p) > (q++)) ? (++p * q++): (q++ - ++p);;
```

However confusing, this expression does not have undefined behavior: there is a sequence point *Between the evaluations of the first operand of the conditional ?: operator and whichever of the second and third operands is evaluated (C17 6.5.15)*.

Considering the initial values `p = 7, q = 6, r = 4`, the test expression is evaluated first: `(++p) > (q++)` with these steps:

- `p` is incremented to `8`
- `8` is compared to `6`, `8 > 6` is true
- `q` is incremented to `7`

There is a sequence point between the `?` and whichever expression is evaluated depending on the truth value, so `p` and `q` are incremented before this evaluation proceeds. Note that the C Standard does not specify when this incrementation occurs, just that the incremented value of `p` and the initial value of `q` are used for the comparison.

Since the test is true, `(++p * q++)` is evaluated:

- `p` is incremented to `9`
- `9 * 7` evaluates to `63`
- `r` is incremented by `63`, its value is changed to `67`.
- `q` is incremented to `8`.

The same remark regarding the incrementation of `p` and `q` as above is appropriate here too.

The extra `;` has no effect, it is an empty statement.

Finally `printf("%d%d,%d", p, q, r);` outputs the values of `p` and `q` without a space in between and `r` is output after a comma. Hence the output is:

```
98,67
```

QED

Note that the macro is not properly parenthesized and has a spurious `;` at the end, it should be:

```
#define FNC(x,y)  ((x) > (y) ? (x) * (y) : (y) - (x))
```

Furthermore, this macro should not be invoked in code with argument expressions that have side effects as these side effects happen twice in the expansion.

Comment: Good notes at the end about "should"s.